# Problems logging into Facebook with C# Winforms

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms

Hi so I'm creating a simple C# Winform application that will let users login to facebook. So far, when I run the program, a message "The parameter app_id is required". In my code below, I have added my app_id but it is still not working. How can I fix this? On the designer portion of the form, I just added the WebBrowser on the form. Nothing too fancy. The code for this form is below. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Facebook;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const string AppId = "{APP_ID}";
        private Uri _loginUrl;
        private const string _ExtendedPermissions = "user_about_me,publish_stream,offline_access";
        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Login();
        }

        private void Login()
        {

            dynamic parameters = fbClient.Get("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = "{APP_ID}",
                client_secret = "{SECRET_KEY}",
                grant_type = "client_credentials"
            });

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_ExtendedPermissions))
                parameters.scope = _ExtendedPermissions;

            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            _loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);

            webBrowserLogin.Navigate(_loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited out the sensitive information from your code, please be more careful in the future as the information you left in could have enabled ANYONE to misuse your facebook application.

Comment: You just declared a const with the app id but it's never used anywhere

Comment: Try looking at this tutorial so that everything is done in the right order: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html